# Trocar conteúdo data-zoom e src sem jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou mexendo em um superzoom porém preciso fazer com que ao clicar nas miniaturas ele altere o src e o data-zoom da imagem principal porém sem o uso do jquery.

Outro detalhe importante é que estas imagens serão dinâmicas, podendo conter de 1 a 10 por exemplo.

https://jsfiddle.net/f30359u3/2/

Este aqui é o superzoom que estou usando.

https://codepen.io/imgix/pen/WrRmLb

Ou se conhecerem outro modo simples de leve de fazer isto também seria de grande ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Separei as tarefas em partes para que você consiga entender o que precisa ser feito.

1. Adicione um evento `listener` nas imagens menores
2. Trocar a imagem principal quando o clique nas imagens menores for detectado

Sabendo disso temos:

```
// Pega todos os elementos das miniaturas
var minis = document.querySelectorAll('#miniatura img');

// Pega a imagem principal
var main = document.querySelector('.superzoom img');

/**
 * Realize um loop em todas as miniaturas adicionando
 * o evento "click" em todas as imagens
 */ 
minis.forEach(function(element) {
    element.addEventListener('click', function() {
    main.src = this.src; // Altera o src da imagem principal pelo da miniatura
    main.dataset.zoom = this.src; // Altera a imagem do data-zoom
  });
});
```

**Não esqueça de usar uma imagem `grande` para as miniaturas, pois ao trocar, a imagem grande assumira o tamanho da que foi clicada.**

Comment: Então, isso não funcionaria, pois tenho de trocar também a imagem do data-zoom.

De qualquer modo preciso que as 2 sejam trocadas e colocando as duas com o tamanho máximo o carregamento ficaria muito pesado.

Comment: @RodrigoB.Silva o conceito da resposta é perfeito para o que você precisa, adicionei mais uma linha para trocar o `data-zoom` como você solicitou, mas a respeito de ficar "pesado" não esta em questão para resolver o problema, acredito que a questão de desempenho seria melhor respondida em outra pergunta a parte desta.